# Send an SMS using user's phone number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, sms, messaging

I found several questions and answers that use an API like Twilio or Amazon to send SMS messages, but what I wanna know is whether there is a way to use the user's phone number to send an SMS message using Javascript. I am working on a desktop app that uses ElectronJs and ReactJs. Thank you.

Comment: You need to send the data to an SMS API

Comment: You cant, like @charlietfl mentioned, use an SMS API. Maximum you can do is href sms:《number》